# Can't insert to database in wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

I tried to insert values to database table in wordpress, but it is showing some errors as below

[type] => 2048 
[message] => is_a(): Deprecated. Please use the instanceof operator 
[file] => /var/www/html/workbench/Shinod/wordpress/wp-includes/classes.php 
[line] => 724

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the function `is_a()` somewhere in your code - it was deprecated in PHP 5.0.0 in favour of the `instanceof` operator, but was re-classified again in PHP 5.3.0.

Check the [PHP manual on `is_a()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-a.php).

Answer (score 1):

It's not an error, it's E_STRICT message.
It shouldn't interrupt communication with mysql.

Answer (score 0):

That is a PHP warning, not a fatal error.  The site will still function.  That's not what's stopping you from inserting data into your database.  You need to look harder to find (and post) the real error that's stopping you.